# How to upgrade the Bot Framework WebChat (1.3) to 1.5 and is this available?

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I am trying add a table in my Bot Framework webchat adaptive Card, but it displays this error `[Warning] The selected Target Version (1.6) is greater than the version supported by Bot Framework WebChat (1.3)` How to upgrade the version of webchat framework now ?

Comment: You can go through the thread - https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/4226

Comment: but in the change.MD of adaptive card it says they released 2.11 for adaptive cards https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#changed-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documents/FAQ(https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/4234), detailed the steps to check for version matching with `botframework-webchat` and `adaptivecards`.

Findings/Analysis: I have `botframework-webchat` version *4.14.0*, and `adaptivecards` version *2.9.0* which will not support schema greater than 1.4 according to the  *New Policy Version* (https://www.npmjs.com/package/adaptivecards).

From the FAQ(https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/4234) I need to have `botframework-webchat` version of *4.15.0* and `adaptivecards` version of *2.10* which will support upto adaptivecards schema 1.5 schema.

Once I upgraded the latest version of `botframework-webchat` to *4.15.9* it also upgraded the `adpativecards` version to *2.11.1*, which supports the latest schemas.

Screenshot of botframework-webchat version and showing adpativecards version upgrade.

[image]